# Performance issues re-sizing large amount of components on form resize

Tags: delphi

I feel my failure so far lies in search terms as information on this has to be pretty common. Basically I am looking for common solutions and best practices when performing resizes on several components while a form is resized.

I have a form with a component that is based upon `TScrollBox`. The ScrollBox contains rows which are added dynamically at run time.  They are basically a subcomponent.  Each one has an image on the left and a memo on the right.  The height is set based upon the width and aspect ratio of the image.  Upon the resize of the scroll box a loop sets the width of the rows triggering the rows own internal resize.  The loop also sets the relative top position if the heights have changed.

Screen shot:

[image]

Around 16 rows performs fine.  My goal is closer to 32 rows which is very choppy and can peg a core at 100% usage.

**I have tried:**

- Added a check to prevent a new resize starting while the previous has yet to complete. It answered if it occured and it does sometimes.
- I tried preventing it resizing more often than every 30 ms which would allow for 30 frame per second drawing.  Mixed results.
- Changed the rows base component from TPanel to TWinControl.  Not sure if there is a performance penalty using the Panel but its an old habit.
- With and without double buffering.

I would like to allow row resizing to occur during a resize as a preview to how large the image will be in the row.  That eliminates one obvious solution that in some applications is an acceptable loss.

Right now the resize code internally for the row is completely dynamic and based upon the dimensions of each image.  Next thing I plan to try is to basically specify the Aspect Ratio, Max Width/Height based on the largest image in the collection.  This should reduce the amount of math per row.  But it seems like the issues are more the resize event and the loop itself?

Full unit code for the components:

```
unit rPBSSVIEW;

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls, Forms, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, Graphics, SysUtils, rPBSSROW, Windows, Messages;

type
  TPBSSView = class(TScrollBox)
  private    
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure ResizeRows(Sender: TObject);
    procedure AddRow(FileName: String);
    procedure FillRow(Row: Integer; ImageStream: TMemoryStream);
  end;

var
  PBSSrow: Array of TPBSSRow;
  Resizingn: Boolean;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Standard', [TScrollBox]);
end;

procedure TPBSSView.AddRow(FileName: String);
begin
  SetLength(PBSSrow,(Length(PBSSrow) + 1));
  PBSSrow[Length(PBSSrow)-1] := TPBSSRow.create(self);
  With PBSSrow[Length(PBSSrow)-1] do
  begin
    Left := 2;
    if (Length(PBSSrow)-1) = 0 then Top := 2 else Top := ((PBSSRow[Length(PBSSRow) - 2].Top + PBSSRow[Length(PBSSRow) - 2].Height) + 2);
    Width := (inherited ClientWidth - 4);
    Visible := True;
    Parent := Self;
    PanelLeft.Caption := FileName;
  end;
end;

procedure TPBSSView.FillRow(Row: Integer; ImageStream: TMemoryStream);
begin
  PBSSRow[Row].LoadImageFromStream(ImageStream);
end;

procedure TPBSSView.ResizeRows(Sender: TObject);
var
  I, X: Integer;
begin
  if Resizingn then exit
  else
  begin
      Resizingn := True;
      HorzScrollBar.Visible := False;
      X := (inherited ClientWidth - 4);
      if Length(PBSSrow) > 0 then
      for I := 0 to Length(PBSSrow) - 1 do
      Begin
        PBSSRow[I].Width := X; //Set Width
        if not (I = 0) then      //Move all next ones down.
          begin
            PBSSRow[I].Top := (PBSSRow[(I - 1)].Top + PBSSRow[(I - 1)].Height) + 2;
          end;
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      End;
    HorzScrollBar.Visible := True;
    Resizingn := False;
  end;
end;

constructor TPBSSView.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  OnResize := ResizeRows;
  DoubleBuffered := True;
  VertScrollBar.Tracking := True;
  Resizingn := False;
end;

destructor TPBSSView.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

Row Code:

```
unit rPBSSROW;

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls, Forms, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, Graphics, pngimage, SysUtils;

type
  TPBSSRow = class(TWinControl)
  private
    FImage: TImage;
    FPanel: TPanel;
    FMemo: TMemo;
    FPanelLeft: TPanel;
    FPanelRight: TPanel;
    FImageWidth: Integer;
    FImageHeight: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure MyPanelResize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure LeftPanelResize(Sender: TObject);
  published
    procedure LoadImageFromStream(ImageStream: TMemoryStream);
    property Image: TImage read FImage;
    property Panel: TPanel read FPanel;
    property PanelLeft: TPanel read FPanelLeft;
    property PanelRight: TPanel read FPanelRight;
  end;

procedure Register;    

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Standard', [TWinControl]);
end;

procedure TPBSSRow.MyPanelResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Width - 466) <= FImageWidth then FPanelLeft.Width := (Width - 466)
else FPanelLeft.Width := FImageWidth;
  FPanelRight.Width := (Width - FPanelLeft.Width);
end;

procedure TPBSSRow.LeftPanelResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  AspectRatio: Extended;
begin
  FPanelRight.Left := (FPanelLeft.Width);
  //Enforce Info Minimum Height or set Height
  if FImageHeight > 0 then  AspectRatio := (FImageHeight/FImageWidth) else
  AspectRatio := 0.4;
  if (Round(AspectRatio * FPanelLeft.Width)) >= 212 then
  begin
    Height := (Round(AspectRatio * FPanelLeft.Width));
    FPanelLeft.Height := Height;
    FPanelRight.Height := Height;
  end
  else
  begin
    Height :=212;
    FPanelLeft.Height := Height;
    FPanelRight.Height := Height;
  end;
  if Fimage.Height >= FImageHeight then FImage.Stretch := False else Fimage.Stretch := True;
  if Fimage.Width >= FImageWidth then FImage.Stretch := False else Fimage.Stretch := True;
end;

procedure TPBSSRow.LoadImageFromStream(ImageStream: TMemoryStream);
var
  P: TPNGImage;
  n: Integer;
begin
  P := TPNGImage.Create;
  ImageStream.Position := 0;
  P.LoadFromStream(ImageStream);
  FImage.Picture.Assign(P);
  FImageWidth := P.Width;
  FImageHeight := P.Height;
end;

constructor TPBSSRow.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
    BevelInner := bvNone;
    BevelOuter := bvNone;
    BevelKind :=  bkNone;
    Color := clWhite;
    OnResize := MyPanelResize;
    DoubleBuffered := True;
  //Left Panel for Image
  FPanelLeft := TPanel.Create(Self);
  with FPanelLeft do
  begin
    SetSubComponent(true);
    Align := alLeft;
    Parent := Self;
    //SetBounds(0,0,100,100);
    ParentBackground := False;
    Color := clBlack;
    Font.Color := clLtGray;
    Constraints.MinWidth := 300;
    BevelInner := bvNone;
    BevelOuter := bvNone;
    BevelKind :=  bkNone;
    BorderStyle := bsNone;
    OnResize := LeftPanelResize;
  end;
  //Image for left panel
  FImage := TImage.Create(Self);
  FImage.SetSubComponent(true);
  FImage.Align := alClient;
  FImage.Parent := FPanelLeft;
  FImage.Center := True;
  FImage.Stretch := True;
  FImage.Proportional := True;
  //Right Panel for Info
  FPanelRight := TPanel.Create(Self);
  with FPanelRight do
  begin
    SetSubComponent(true);
    Parent := Self;
    Padding.SetBounds(2,5,5,2);
    BevelInner := bvNone;
    BevelOuter := bvNone;
    BevelKind :=  bkNone;
    BorderStyle := bsNone;
    Color := clLtGray;
  end;

  //Create Memo in Right Panels
  FMemo := TMemo.create(self);
  with FMemo do
  begin
    SetSubComponent(true);
    Parent := FPanelRight;
    Align := alClient;
    BevelOuter := bvNone;
    BevelInner := bvNone;
    BorderStyle := bsNone;
    Color := clLtGray;
  end;

end;

destructor TPBSSRow.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You could try  LockWindowUpdate(handle); <your Loop>  LockWindowUpdate(0);

Comment: @bummi Read the documentation for `LockWindowUpdate`. This is one of those API functions that is routinely abused in much the same was that `ProcessMessages` is abused.

Comment: Yeah I was told that was a bad thing to do.  Alright anyways the full unit code for the 2 components has been added.  The thing was David.  The development of this has halted at the most basic step.  There is almost nothing I can cut from this code.  Its purely resizing and loading the image, parsing the png chunk text.  I am currently already in a state of proof of concept.  Its basically an example program at this point.  I havent developed it any further.  Its worth noting there some left overs in there and some things ive been toggling back and forth.

Comment: Before trying to prevent updates in the loop, try removing 'ProcessMessages' which processes updates with each iteration.

Comment: Alright I will try that Sertac.  I added it to help with certain things which it did but as you say it actually allows the thread to break out of what its doing and start other things.  @David another thing worth mentioning.  I made a "codeless" example which was nothing but aligned panels.  The initial performance problem is universal.  When you have 100 components adjusting to the size of each other there are performance issues.  I can only assume code can be added to mitigate the problem such as not performing uncessary operations.

Comment: Also want to note as I read through this the constraints code was added later so it kinda makes some of the old size code irrelevant.

Comment: The simplest possible example is what we want to see.

Comment: Well without the image loading the height sizing never goes into effect.  The ONLY thing removable is the mouse wheel up and the PNG chunk thats it so a couple lines of code.  But done on those.  The 300 pixel constraint was added to the one panel actually because of the fact that no image loaded means the sizing is messed.

Comment: This question essentially distills to *"I need a faster image rendering implementation than TImage -- what can I use?"*

Comment: Are you saying you think the TImage is slowing down everything else?  Even when the code is reduced so the image does not resize and only the width of the text panel change the performance is still bad.  I have no reason to think the TImage is the problem.  My question boils down to common practices to improve performance with a large number of scaled components.  If someone where writing a book they might list 10 concepts a few of which would work in different applications.  I think its re sizing too often but cant stop it.  It should only happen first, last and every 30 ms inbetween yes?

Comment: Yes, TImage (and the other VCL components - TPanel, etc) are not meant to be used like this - it is terribly inefficient.  VCL Forms applications are not graphics applications - they are not even remotely optimized for this type of work.  The only acceptable solution to this is probably going to be to go back to the drawing board and do this with DirectX or something more suitable.

Comment: Does this question apply to runtime or designtime? Because I see a lot of design-code, but your register procedures are wrong. (That may well be not part of the problem, but just asking for my understanding).

Comment: @J - While there is always room for graphic performance increases using DirectX/OpenGL.  I have never seen a program like say Nikon ViewNX use DirectX to list images in rows with property data. @NGLN The register was there from an example I never register the component.  I am not sure how to answer. We NEVER know the image size until the moment the user loads.  The images are downloaded from an FTP server.  Unknown image properties, unknown amount of rows.  There is some uneeded design code for testing. This is in development stage 1 of 100. Im working out 1 component in a much larger app.

Comment: With J's initial assessment of the problems. I now venture to a middle ground.  How about drawing the rows and images with GDI only resorting to the VCL wrappers for such things as the memo where its preferable.  Using the API's directly and only what is needed should see an increase in performance?

Comment: @BrianHolloway That's an alternative.  I don't know that you will get liquid-smooth scaling with GDI/GDI+, but doing all your own drawing directly is likely to improve things.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using, btw?

Comment: 2K9 sadly.  License actually belongs to my mothers data entry company which we used to develop database applications for.  I started out on 3 a long long time ago as a kid.  I was actually debating today XE4 Starter license.  I started to study C++ the only real thing holding me here is its my "native" language.  Faster to get things done.  Since I develop for myself, not for profit etc the XE4 Starter as an "upgrade" is probably appropriate.  But I still sit here with no 64 bit compiler locked into a language with little free support.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A few tips:

- `TWinControl` already ís a container, you do not need another panel inside it to add controls
- You do not need an `TImage` component to view a graphic, that can also with `TPaintBox`, or as in my example control below, a `TCustomControl`,
- Since all of your other panels are not recognizable (borders and bevels are disabled), loose them altogether and place the `TMemo` directly on your row control,
- `SetSubComponent` is only for design time usage. You do not need it. Nor the `Register` procedures for that matter.
- Put the global rows array inside your class definition, otherwise multiple `TPBSSView` controls will use the same array!
- `TWinControl` already tracks all its child controls, so you won't need the array anyway, see my example below,
- Make use of the `Align` property to save you from realigning manually,
- If the memo control is just for showing text, then remove it and paint the text yourself.

Try this one for starters:

```
unit PBSSView;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, Classes, Controls, SysUtils, Graphics, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls,
  Forms, PngImage;

type
  TPBSSRow = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FGraphic: TPngImage;
    FStrings: TStringList;
    function ImageHeight: Integer; overload;
    function ImageHeight(ControlWidth: Integer): Integer; overload;
    function ImageWidth: Integer; overload;
    function ImageWidth(ControlWidth: Integer): Integer; overload;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWmEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMWindowPosChanging(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanging);
      message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure RequestAlign; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure LoadImageFromStream(Stream: TMemoryStream);
    property Strings: TStringList read FStrings;
  end;

  TPBSSView = class(TScrollBox)
  private
    function GetRow(Index: Integer): TPBSSRow;
    procedure WMEnterSizeMove(var Message: TMessage); message WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWmEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure WMExitSizeMove(var Message: TMessage); message WM_EXITSIZEMOVE;
  protected
    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure AddRow(const FileName: TFileName);
    procedure FillRow(Index: Integer; ImageStream: TMemoryStream);
    property Rows[Index: Integer]: TPBSSRow read GetRow;
  end;

implementation

{ TPBSSRow }

constructor TPBSSRow.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Width := 300;
  Height := 50;
  FStrings := TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TPBSSRow.Destroy;
begin
  FStrings.Free;
  FGraphic.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TPBSSRow.ImageHeight: Integer;
begin
  Result := ImageHeight(Width);
end;

function TPBSSRow.ImageHeight(ControlWidth: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if (FGraphic <> nil) and not FGraphic.Empty then
    Result := Round(ImageWidth(ControlWidth) * FGraphic.Height / FGraphic.Width)
  else
    Result := Height;
end;

function TPBSSRow.ImageWidth: Integer;
begin
  Result := ImageWidth(Width);
end;

function TPBSSRow.ImageWidth(ControlWidth: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := ControlWidth div 2;
end;

procedure TPBSSRow.LoadImageFromStream(Stream: TMemoryStream);
begin
  FGraphic.Free;
  FGraphic := TPngImage.Create;
  Stream.Position := 0;
  FGraphic.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  Height := ImageHeight + Padding.Bottom;
end;

procedure TPBSSRow.Paint;
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, ImageWidth, ImageHeight), FGraphic);
  SetRect(R, ImageWidth, 0, Width, ImageHeight);
  Canvas.FillRect(R);
  Inc(R.Left, 10);
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, FStrings.Text, -1, R, DT_EDITCONTROL or
    DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_NOFULLWIDTHCHARBREAK or DT_NOPREFIX or DT_WORDBREAK);
  Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, ImageHeight, Width, Height));
end;

procedure TPBSSRow.RequestAlign;
begin
  {eat inherited}
end;

procedure TPBSSRow.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWmEraseBkgnd);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TPBSSRow.WMWindowPosChanging(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanging);
begin
  inherited;
  if (FGraphic <> nil) and not FGraphic.Empty then
    Message.WindowPos.cy := ImageHeight(Message.WindowPos.cx) + Padding.Bottom;
end;

{ TPBSSView }

procedure TPBSSView.AddRow(const FileName: TFileName);
var
  Row: TPBSSRow;
begin
  Row := TPBSSRow.Create(Self);
  Row.Align := alTop;
  Row.Padding.Bottom := 2;
  Row.Parent := Self;
end;

constructor TPBSSView.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  VertScrollBar.Tracking := True;
end;

procedure TPBSSView.FillRow(Index: Integer; ImageStream: TMemoryStream);
begin
  Rows[Index].LoadImageFromStream(ImageStream);
end;

function TPBSSView.GetRow(Index: Integer): TPBSSRow;
begin
  Result := TPBSSRow(Controls[Index]);
end;

procedure TPBSSView.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
  {eat inherited}
end;

procedure TPBSSView.WMEnterSizeMove(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if not AlignDisabled then
    DisableAlign;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TPBSSView.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWmEraseBkgnd);
var
  DC: HDC;
begin
  DC := GetDC(Handle);
  try
    FillRect(DC, Rect(0, VertScrollBar.Range, Width, Height), Brush.Handle);
  finally
    ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
  end;
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TPBSSView.WMExitSizeMove(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if AlignDisabled then
    EnableAlign;
end;

end.
```

[image: Screen shot]

If this still performs badly, then there are multiple other enhancements possible.

#### Update:

- Flickering eliminated by overriding/intercepting `WM_ERASEBKGND` (and intercepting `PaintWindow` for versions < XE2),
- Better performance by making use of [`DisableAlign`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DisableAlign) and `EnableAlign`.

Comment: I will try it out later today.  For the foreseeable future there will only be one scrollbox component so no overlap in array usage.  However who knows what it may evolve to. I appreciate your work on this example and this likely will be accepted as the answer. I usually wait 24 hours before doing so.

Comment: This is nice.  I've also often resorted to Erik Bilsen's GDI+ libraries - there are some nice features to work with there.  I've always found that with just overriding `Paint` on a custom control, even with double buffering and killing `WM_ERASEBKGND`, there is always some leftover flicker.  Still, this is much faster than the OP and looks much better.   http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml

Comment: I have one issue so far.  Setting the row height after the fact.  Right now as the images expand to their full height they are either overlapping each other or just into each row.  Either way setting height in the resize event causes access violations.  Not sure where I am lost in this.

Comment: @BrianHolloway I don't know how this looks on your system - I always end up with some residual flicker.  In cases like this I deal with it by overriding `CreateParams` on the offending control and adding `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` to the window style - this prevents the parent control from trying to paint the same area as its children.  I've edited the answer to include this.

Comment: @J... Eating inherited from `PaintWindow` also reduces flicker, but here in XE2, `TScrollBox` already dóes that. Added it though for previous versions.

Comment: @J... TScrollBox hás `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` by default, but I seem to have removed it with setting the `ControlStyle`. Changed and undone it. Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Hey, that's actually even better.  I noticed scrolling artifacts afterwards when adding `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` - I'd fixed it with `Invalidate` after `inherited` overriding `WMHScroll` and `WMVScroll`.  Simply nixing the ControlStyle setting in the constructor sidestepped the issue entirely, however.  Very nice.

Comment: I will take a look into it.  Dev system has a GTX 570 not sure how it affects 2d performance over the average system.  But I run everything past my laptop which has a Core2Duo and 9800M GS that can barely play back 1080P video as a baseline for older but capable systems.

Comment: I tested the latest changes and its beautiful.  Have to disable double buffer on the form which is fine.  64 rows performs great which is a goal. I appreciate the enormous amount of help given here.  It not only helps deliver a better working solution to the people I am doing this for which is being done for free.  I have learned some things in the process that go way beyond the initial problem.  I can't wait to get back to this now.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will make a significant difference, but instead setting PBSSRow[I].Width and PBSSRow[I].Top separately, make one call to PBSSRow[I].SetBounds instead. This will save you one Resize event for that SubComponent.

Comment: I appreciate this tip.  I am bad about some of these simple optimizations that are obvious.  Sometimes they are implemented in later code.  Sometimes not at all.