# How to handle WM_ERASEBKGND to avoid flickering?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7, gdi, flicker

I have on a form some custom progress bars which are updated/refreshed twice per second and they are flickering.

```
TMyProgressBar = class(TCustomControl)
```

I inherited the control from `TCustomControl`, because I needed `Handle` and some `TWinControl` events. The controls (up to 64 items) are created dynamically and put on a ScrollBox. When progress is updated I first call `InvalidateRect`.

All painting work (a set of rectangles, `DrawText`, etc - inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044125/delphi-draw-own-progress-bar-in-list-view)) are performed in a memory DC and then `BitBlt`-ed on the control's DC. It is anyway flickering, it seems like component dis-appears and re-appears. IMHO it is caused by background erasing.

In [this flickering-free drawing advice](http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc052102g.htm) it is written to handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` in the following way:

```
type
  TMyProgressBar = class(TCustomControl)
    procedure WMEraseBkGnd(var Message:TMessage); message WM_ERASEBKGND;

procedure TMyProgressBar.WMEraseBkGnd(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;
```

But in another component, by TMS (`TAdvProgressBar`), `Result` is set to `0` for the same message.

Now [the Windows documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states:

> An application should return nonzero if it erases the background;
>   otherwise, it should return zero.

I tested both variants (Result = 0, 1), and to my surprise both avoid flickering.

So now, what do I have to put in my Delphi code? What is the correct way?

Comment: Return 1, you're, likely, not going to benefit from keeping the update region marked for erasing.

Comment: This is not really a cure all. There might be work that really needs to be done in `WM_ERASEBACKGROUND`. For sure if you paint nothing then you'll have no flicker.

Comment: There is a really great example of a custom `TScrollBox` that is tuned to combat flicker : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16569324/327083

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't matter. What matters is, as long as you don't call `inherited`, default window procedure will not erase the background. Since you're painting the whole surface of the control, you don't need default processing.

What changes when you return '0' or '1' (not '0') is that, when `BeginPaint` is called, the system sets the `fErase` member of the `PAINTSTRUCT` accordingly. When you return '0', it is set 'True', indicating that the background must be erased in the paint process. For '1', it is set 'False', indicating that no erasing is necessary. `BeginPaint` is called in `TWinControl.PaintHandler`. No one ever checks what `fErase` is, VCL only uses the device context `BeginPaint` returns, so what you return does not make any difference.

Still, I'd return '1', conceptually hinting that erasing have been taken care of.

Comment: why 0 = TRUE and 1 = FALSE here - it's confusing me? :)

Comment: @ALZ - Return 'True' (1) to 'WM_ERASEBKGND', and you're saying that "OK, erasing done". Thus, then when 'BeginPaint' is called, the system says "Erase: No, you don't have to (False)". In other words, '0' is in response to the message. 'True' is in a completely different place.

Comment: Is it possible to call `inherited` from not `overridden` method (like `procedure WMEraseBkGnd(var Message:TMessage); message WM_ERASEBKGND`)?

Comment: @ALZ - Message handling is special in that regard in Delphi. See #7 here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Declaring_a_New_Message-handling_Method

Answer (score 4):

You should return 0 when the background is not (completely) erased, and you should return another value then 0 when background is to be considered erased. This is the convention by which you have to hold.

More important is not to call `inherited` within this message handler <sup>1)</sup>, which would call the inherited message handlers, and eventually the default Windows procedure which would paint the device context with the brush that is given to the window at creation time, if any.

Now, in practice, and especially in this example of your custom control, it does not really matter which value you return, because you are the only one performing the erasing task. But consider designing a base control class or deployment of the control: you might want to indicate to descendants or users of your control that the background is not totally validated. That's what `Message.Result = 0` means. You could also send back `Message.Result = ebLeftSide` which would indicate that in the current state of the control, only the left side (whatever that might mean) is "erased".

Remember that "erasing" in this context also means "drawing", but that is beyond the question I think.

<sup>1)</sup> `Inherited` works a bit different for message handlers in comparison to virtual methods. Although it means the same - the first handler in the inheritance chain will be called - there is no override directive in its declaration, and the method name cannot be added.

Comment: thanks for response and for your other progress bare idea.
Now it's a little bit clearer for me - new to UI/Graphical development. 
In my case I am overwriting old state (view) of progress ant it doesn't make illusion of flickering, because background is no mo erased.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `WM_ERASEBKND` just determines how the `fErase` member of the `PAINTSTRUCT` gets initialized when you call `BeginPaint` in the subsequent `WM_PAINT` handler.  If your paint handler ignores that member, then it doesn't really matter what `WM_ERASEBKND` returns.

The flicker is avoided by painting once instead of twice.  If you fill the region with a color in `WM_ERASEBKGND` and then blit over it a moment later in `WM_PAINT`, you'll get flicker.  If you do no painting in `WM_ERASEBKGND` and just blit in `WM_PAINT`, you won't flicker.  The only trick is making your blit covers the entire invalidated area with initialized pixels.